# Is there a way to use storage for the Microsoft bot framework conversation dialog instead of the directline service storage for conversation history

Tags: botframework, azure-storage, direct-line-botframework

The paradigm I am understanding for storage of the bot framework is related to state and not necessarily the entire usage of the bot dialog.  This wouldn't be just a transcript but also it would serve as a message history when the user when the user connects to the bot.

The issue would also serve during reconnection to the service.  As of now, where are the messages being stored during reconnection? Or are they not stored and once connection is lost from the user session are all of those messages gone through memory?  Again, is there a way to custom manage this.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion about terminology here. Yes, storage is related to state but "dialogs" are dependent on state. I'm guessing when you say dialog you're not talking about the Bot Builder dialogs library. "Dialog" is a special term in the Bot Framework that refers to a specific component of bot-side logic, something that's used in dialog sets and dialog stacks and accessed through a dialog context with dialog state. Since you're talking about message history, when you say dialog you mean "conversation" which refers to the interactions between a bot and a user. Is that correct?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes, I am referring to message history which I am thinking this is black boxed into the directline service.  For example, how reconnection works that is not coming from the bot framework but rather in directline

Comment: Well Direct Line is actually considered part of the Bot Framework, so maybe you meant the Bot Builder SDK in that case. Direct Line is a channel, which means it facilitates communication between a bot and a client application. However, saying it's part of the Bot Framework doesn't mean you have to use Direct Line, since there are other channels you can use instead.

Comment: Are you saying you're using Direct Line and you want to use the [Send Conversation History API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-conversation-history) to recreate the conversation history when a user rejoins the conversation, but you're not sure how to store the transcript?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes essentially. Where is the storing of the conversation activities?

Comment: and wouldn't you want context of the entire conversation?

Comment: Do you mean you as a bot developer would want the bot to have that context, or do you mean the user would want that context? I'm not sure why a bot would need to know a conversation's history since some bots only respond to one message at a time without taking any context into consideration at all. If you're just talking about the user then is it good enough to use [Get Activities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference#get-activities) to access the activities that are already saved in Direct Line? Or does the bot need them?

Comment: When you say, already saved in DirectLine that is exactly it right there.  How robust is that.  Let me give you a few use cases.  If the user logs out and logs back in is their conversation stored for what period of time in directline?  If the user closes the app and then reopens it is their conversation still stored? If the user changes the device and logs in somewhere else or changes a channel i.e. move over to slack or skype is the conversation available for that channel?  What control is there over directline to store and or retrieve messages?  I don't believe there is any or can you?

Comment: I believe I can answer your questions, but would you please answer mine first? I want to know more about what you want to use this conversation history for.

Comment: @KyleDelaney sure, so the conversation history would be A. for the reconnection and is what the directline service does. but the question is for when and how long is that available in the directline service.  This is where you connect to the con id and watermark.  B. In the case of the user closing the app and hence user session completely, coming back the next day and reconnecting to that user and having the conversation with the bot come back to the user in its entirety.  i.e. conversation history.  This would work if they changed devices or channels too

Comment: @KyleDelaney can we move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200961/discussion-between-christian-matthew-and-kyle-delaney).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any store to store whatever you want. If your bot has access to a user's conversation history then it can use the [Send Conversation History API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-conversation-history) to share the transcript with the client so the client can render it.  This storage history api your client can use, [Get Activities API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-activities), can accesses the Direct Line service store that is available for 24 hours.

If you want to share conversation history across multiple channels then you will need some way to identify the user across multiple channels, and the only way to do that would be to have the user sign in to the bot using an [OAuth connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication). But even if you do all that, you will need to rely on each channel client to be able to display the updated conversation history. I would not expect every client application to have that ability.

Comment: just to ask a few additional details.  The conversation history is stored in directline correct?  there is not really a way to subvert that.  Also, is that history saved for 24 hours?  Is that how the conversation history works?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew - Conversation history is stored in Direct Line for 24 hours. I don't know what you mean when you say there's no way to subvert that, but there is absolutely nothing stopping you from storing activities on your own in addition to the history that gets automatically stored by Direct Line.

Comment: Hi Kyle, maybe I am missing something here and this is kind of the point.  You can save activities on your own but when you are using the streamUrl and the directline api to connect and reconnect what would be the mechanism to reconnect from the frontend to that history?  Seems like it should be the history in the directline api.  Also, saving the history in the application seems like that would NOT be the right place for this to occur.  Mostly because you would have to generate a schema and mechanism to store for each users conversation.  seems like that should be what directline does.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew - You keep asking questions I already answered. I said that the mechanism for clients to access the Direct Line history is the Get Activities API. If you don't like this answer then what will satisfy you?

Comment: You're answer needs to be edited otherwise is won't be exculpatory to the confusion of achieving the answer to the intended question

Comment: @ChristianMatthew - Your edit has been approved. Is my answer acceptable now?

Comment: by no way I am trying to be difficult and I truly had this question for the project I am working on.  To my post the answer is effectively no.  Which is understandable but I feel your answer should express that in fact, the directline conversation history is abstracted away from the developer.  If you put that language in there I will give that as the correct answer.

Comment: Your question is "Is there a way to use storage for the Microsoft bot framework conversation dialog instead of the directline service storage for conversation history?" I don't understand why you think the answer is no. I have been telling you the answer is yes for weeks now. Any program you make can do whatever it wants with Azure storage. If you use CosmosDB for example then you can learn how to access storage with [these docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started). Both your bot and your Direct Line client have the ability to write every activity to storage.

Comment: Ok so how does directline write directly to storage? And then let's say we're using the directline api get history how does that bypass directline and use what's in storage beyond the parameters that are set such as 24 hours access. You'd be bypassing directline. Let me read the docs and see if I'm missing something.

Comment: Perhaps this is the disconnect. Let me ask it this way. What exactly would allow me to take a conversation in it's entirety from directline and store it? I know the front end recieves the communication but are suggesting a simultaneous delivery of that communication be stored as well? Here's the issue with that. Where is all of that payload coming from? The id's the watermarks all the parts that are analogous to what directline stores within its service. I get directline does exactly that but where would you expect the bot to do that process at the same time? That's the part I'm confused on.

Comment: If you want to take a conversation's full history from Direct Line and store it then you would use Get Activities like I keep saying and then write the result to your own storage, hoping that 24 hours haven't passed since the conversation started. If you want to store one activity at a time then you just store each activity as they come. Both the bot and the client have access to every activity on every turn. For example, the client can store every user-to-bot activity when sending them to the bot, and also store every bot-to-user activity when receiving them from the bot.

Comment: I forgot to mention this earlier, but there's actually [a middleware that does this for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#additional-resources) on the bot side. Have a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1380).

Comment: Thank you makes sense with the middleware.  Otherwise a service would be needed to obtain user state outside of the bot such as a front-end process.  I would include that in the answer and an example of using the middleware transcript in both JS and C# would be awesome!

Comment: that transcriptmiddlewarelogger doesn't really work because there isn't a node npm package with the cosmos logger in it.

Comment: [The middleware is already in the Bot Builder SDK.](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/transcriptLogger.ts) You don't need a separate package.

Comment: yes that is there but the cosmos ability to use it in nodejs isn't. specifically this  var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(new CosmosTranscriptStore(config));