# What is all needed to build a custom front-end chatbot solution with the DirectLine api not using the web channel but rather a custom channel

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

One of the first things I came across in building conversational AI systems are the ability to create a custom conversation front-end that is within a custom chat dialog. This can be accomplished in an easier sense but formulating a custom directline channel.

However, is there a way to achieve everything you need to utilize a custom frontend with only a rest api style interface for the client?  Is there documentation regarding this? And lastly, is there a way control and rerender storage that would be used from a stored database of conversation that can be used to rerender the conversation back onto the frontend. i.e. Is there a way to store the entire conversation in sequence for a particular user.

This is in a way described in [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349178/is-there-a-way-to-use-storage-for-the-microsoft-bot-framework-conversation-dialo).

Comment: What you do you mean by a "custom conversation front-end...within a custom chat dialog"?

Comment: As for a "rest api style interface", the Bot Framework REST API provides all the API functionality for communicating with a bot. The [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) tells you how this can be achieved via the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Regarding conversation storage, there are any number of methods available to storing and retrieving conversation transcripts. It is largely going depend on the SDK you are using (C#, Node, etc), if there is an adapter that already exists for connecting to whichever storage service you desire, or if you need to create a custom adapter to achieve your needs.